# Python controlled LCD and Button

Tags: rpi.gpio

I'm trying to use a button to scroll through messages on an LCD display. I got a kit from Amazon which has a whole bunch of buttons, sensors, LEDs, etc.
It also came with code to do various projects, but I want to combine the button press with the display.
I found various code online, and managed to put something together, but it's acting very strange.
When I run it, the message on the display prints a few characters at a time-- very slow. Pauses, slowly prints more, etc., until the string has been printed. It seems to work, and pause between messages until I press the button, as it should, but the display speed of each message is super slow-- printing only a few characters at a time. I suspect it has something to do with a loop/check, constantly checking the button and slowing down the display, but not sure.

Here's my code (it's relatively short).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7


import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import LCD1602
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

Button = 17 # GPIO-24, pin 17
GPIO.setup(Button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
presses = 0

# clear the display
LCD1602.init(0x27, 1)



def my_callback(Button):
    global presses
    # start
    if GPIO.input(Button) == 0:
        # write to terminal
        print "Button Pressed\t", presses
        if presses == 0:
         # write to terminal
         print "First!"
         # write to display
         LCD1602.init(0x27, 1)
         LCD1602.write(0, 0, 'Welcome')
         LCD1602.write(0, 1, 'press button')
        if presses == 1:
         # write to terminal
         print "Second!"
         # write to display
         LCD1602.init(0x27, 1)
         LCD1602.write(0, 0, 'You pressed button!')
         LCD1602.write(0, 1, '..press again.')
        if presses == 2:
         # write to terminal
         print "Third!"
         # write to display
         LCD1602.init(0x27, 1)
         LCD1602.write(0, 0, 'Pressed again!')
         LCD1602.write(0, 1, '(press button).')
        if presses == 3:
         # write to terminal
         print "Forth!"
         # write to display
         LCD1602.init(0x27, 1)
         LCD1602.write(0, 0, 'Scrolling works!')
         LCD1602.write(0, 1, 'press button')
        if presses == 4:
         # write to terminal
         print "Fifth!"
         # write to display
         LCD1602.init(0x27, 1)
         LCD1602.write(0, 0, 'Done!')
         LCD1602.write(0, 1, 'press button.')
        presses += 1
    return # not needed, just for clarity

GPIO.add_event_detect(Button, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback)


try:
    print "Waiting"
    while True:
        pass # replace with any of your code

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    print "\nRelease our used channel(s)"
    GPIO.cleanup([Button])

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm not very good at python, so I don't know the exact commands. But I'm sure the issue would be obvious to someone who knows something about python!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious optimisation is to change

```py
try:
    print "Waiting"
    while True:
        pass # replace with any of your code
```

to

```py
try:
    print "Waiting"
    while True:
        time.sleep(1) # Give other code a chance to run.
```

At the moment you are doing what is called a "busy spin", consuming all the CPU time in your while loop for no purpose.